# Альтернативы _getch() для Windows

Tags: c++

Беда в том, что _getch() считывает некоторые символы дважды и т.о. такой, к примеру, код:

```
    int i = 0;

    _getch();
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    _getch();
    std::cout << i + 1 << std::endl;

    _getch();
    std::cout << i + 2 << std::endl;

    _getch();
    std::cout << i + 3 << std::endl;

    std::system("pause");
```

работает некорректно при нажатии на, допустим, delete(игнорирует следующий _getch()).

Какие есть альтернативы или костыли непосредственно для Windows, чтобы все работало нормально? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не наблюдаю такого поведения. Нажатие delete приводит к такому же эффекту, как и любая другая клавиша. Какой у вас компилятор / система?

Comment: Пробовал на MinGW и на VS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Особенность `_getch` в следующем: если нажата 'обычная' клавиша (любой печатаемый символ) функция возвращает ascii-код нажатой клавиши, если же нажата специальная или управляющая клавиша (стрелки, f1-f12) тогда функция возвращает специальный число маркер **и** оставляет в буфере еще один символ (когда у вас `_getch` срабатывал два раза).

Но на этом особенности не заканчиваются. Продемонстрирую на примере следущую возможную проблему:

Допустим у нас есть код: `int a = _getch(); int b = _getch();`и мы хотим таким образом обработать нажатие специальных клавиш.

1. Мы нажимаем стрелку влево. В переменную `a` записывается одно значение.
2. В очереди остается значение, поэтому после второго вызова `_getch` в `b` записывается значение из очереди.
   Здесь и кроется проблема - это значение может быть идентично с каким-нибудь печатаемым символом. И разобрать был введен символ или стрелка невозможно.

Собственно, решение. Пользуйтесь.

---

**windows console input tools (заголовочный файл)**

```
#include <conio.h> // _getch, _kbhit

// специальные клавиши
enum class keyboard : unsigned short
{
    enter   = 13,
    escape  = 27,
    space   = 32,
    bspace  = 8,
    tab     = 9,
    del     = 83,
    left    = 300, // для спец символов сами придумываем значения > 255 (для char)
    up,
    right, 
    down,
    cup,
    home,
    end,
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4,
    f5,
    f6,
    f7,
    f8,
    f9,
    f10,
    f11
};

// возвращает нажатый символ
int get_key();

// возвращает нажатый символ, если была нажата клавиша
// или 0 - если клавиша не нажата
int aget_key();

// очищает очередь нажатий с клавиатуры
void flush();
```

**windows console input tools (реализация)**

```
// включение заголовочного файла 

// реальные ascii-кода
enum ascii_codes
{
  ascii_Home = 71,
  ascii_End = 79,
  ascii_Right = 77,
  ascii_Left = 75,
  ascii_Up = 72,
  ascii_Down = 80,
  ascii_F1 = 59,
  ascii_F2, // дальше +1
  ascii_F3,
  ascii_F4,
  ascii_F5,
  ascii_F6,
  ascii_F7,
  ascii_F8,
  ascii_F9,
  ascii_F10,
  ascii_F11
};

// общая реализация, дальше будет понятно зачем
int _common_get_key()
{
   auto key = _getch(); // считываем
   if (_kbhit())        // проверяем есть ли в очереди еще символы
   {                    // если есть - значит нажата спец.клавиша
       key = _getch();  // считываем следующий символ
       // хардкодим
       switch (key)
       {
           case ascii_Home: return static_cast<int>(keyboard::home);
           case ascii_End: return static_cast<int>(keyboard::end);
           // далее по аналогии
           // ...
       }
   }
   return key;
}

// flush реализация
void flush()
{
    while (_kbhit()) // пока есть символы
        _getch();    // извлекаем их
}  

// get_key реализация
int get_key()
{
    // дабы избежать неприятностей get_key всегда должен
    // очищать очередь перед чтением
    flush();
    return _common_get_key();
}

// aget_key реализация
int aget_key()
{
    if (_kbhit()) // клавиша нажата?
        return _common_get_key(); // возврат без очистки очереди
    // клавиша не нажата, по договоренности return 0
    return 0;
}
```

Для комфортного использования перечисления `keyboard` можно в заголовочный файл добавить следующие шаблоны:

**tools**

```
#include <xutility> // std::enable_if, std::is_same, std::is_integral, std::underlying_type

        template <typename _Left,
            typename _Right,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<
            (std::is_integral_v<_Left> && std::is_same_v<keyboard, std::decay_t<_Right>>)
            ||
            (std::is_integral_v<_Right> && std::is_same_v<keyboard, std::decay_t<_Left>>)
            >>
            inline constexpr bool
            operator==(_Left left, _Right right) noexcept
        {
            return (static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<keyboard>>(left)
                == static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<keyboard>>(right));
        }

        template <typename _Left,
            typename _Right,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<
            (std::is_integral_v<_Left> && std::is_same_v<keyboard, std::decay_t<_Right>>)
            ||
            (std::is_integral_v<_Right> && std::is_same_v<keyboard, std::decay_t<_Left>>)
            >>
            inline constexpr bool
            operator!=(_Left left, _Right right) noexcept
        {
            return (static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<keyboard>>(left)
                != static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<keyboard>>(right));
        }
```

note: [sfinae](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

---

Пример использования:

**test**

```
// includes
#include <iostream>    

int main()
{
    int key = 0;
    do
    {
        // можно поэксперементировать с асинхронным вводом
        key = get_key();
        if (key == keyboard::left)
            std::cout << "Left arrow was pressed\n";
        else if (key == keyboard::enter)
            std::cout << "Enter was pressed\n";
        else if (key == 'F')
            std::cout << "'F' key was pressed\n";
        } while (key != keyboard::escape);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Не забывайте, что это решение только для систем Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Это не беда, а большая и нужная вещь :)

Как вы отличите, какой +, например, нажат - обычный или "серый"? Как вы отловите функциональные клавиши? Стрелки?

А он это все позволяет отлавливать! Именно возвращая для таких клавиш пару символов (т.е. возвращая в двух вызовах два байта).

А если вам просто для остановки - ну, напишите типа

```
_getch(); while(kbhit()) _getch();
```

(надо только посмотреть, там подчеркивание нужно или нет в `kbhit`).

Comment: Нет, это лишь пример. А как тогда сделать так, чтобы следующий _getch() не игнорировался? Или в цикле вызвать 2 гетча?

Comment: Читать первый. Если это - расширенный код (0 или 0xE0) - читать второй раз. И читать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx), только внимательно...

Answer (score -1):

В общем, если это будет кому-то полезно: чтобы обрабатывались нажатия на стрелки в цикле типа:

```
while(1)
{
  int button = _getch();
  if(button == 80)//сделать что-то при нажатии на стрелку
}
```

Я добавил еще один _getch() в начале. И все заработало.
Поправьте, пожалуйста, если я несу какую-то чушь.

Comment: Ну вот Вы использовали какой-то магический трюк, который Вам позволил добиться результата. Вы научились хоть чему-то в результате? А если бы посмотрели [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/078sfkak.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), то узнали бы, что для стрелок (и функциональных клавиш) `getch` нужно вызывать 2 раза, но делать второй вызов нужно только тогда, когда первый вернул `0`.

Comment: @ixSci 0 или 0xE0..