# Меню в консоли через C++

Tags: c++, windows

заинтересовала одна вещь и возможность ее реализации. Хочу создать меню выбора в Командной строке на C++, это должно выглядеть примерно так:

[image: вот так я хочу]

Т.е. пункты меню выбираются стрелками на клавиатуре и нажатием на Enter(так же, если это возможно, нажатием мыши)
Я не прошу кода, я хочу получить пинок в нужном направлении. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Операционная система?

Comment: скорее всего  винда

Comment: Можно использовать [SetConsoleCursorPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770853/how-to-use-setconsolecursorposition-func), [_getch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867475/%d0%90%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b-getch-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-windows) и [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute). Для Windows

Comment: @acade Да, у меня Windows. Спасибо буду изучать!

Comment: Может сразу https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses ?

Comment: @donRumata а смысл? Других ОС, судя по неуказанию текущей, явно не существует, зачем связываться с какими-то переносимостями, теряя в скорости?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, ну в профиле ОП есть тег 'Android', так что не исключено, что кроссплатформенность так или иначе когда-нибудь всплывёт.